# How to close specified opened folders using batch file

Tags: batch-file, file-io

Three days ago I was trying to close folders using batch file, I've checked multiple sites for the script and none of them worked. For example I open manually without `start` the folder "CD_Restored" which is located in C: then I open a batch file inside it to close it, so I wrote:

```
TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq CD_Restored" /IM explorer.exe
```

and I got this message:

> "information: no in-service task matches the specified criteria"

Also I've wrote:

```
@echo off
set shell = createobject("wscript.shell") : if shell.appactivate("CD_Restored") then shell.sendkeys "%{F4}"
```

and didn't work either

Comment: What do you mean with "close folders"? Have you tried to open a folder with `start` (e.g.: `start CD_restored`) and then you want to close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

```
@echo off

cd /d C:\
start C:\Windows\explorer.exe CD_Restored
pause

rem Terminate process:
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq CD_Restored" /IM explorer.exe > nul
if NOT %errorlevel% EQU 0 (echo It seems that Window title named "CD_Restored" doesn't exist!) else (echo Process successfuly terminated!)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try with [sendkeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat):

```
call sendKeys.bat "CD_Restored" "%{F4}"
```

but it will work only if the folder window is NOT minimized.